# Why is magento missing a type class for bundle products?

Tags: bundled-product, development, class

I am looking at a section of code that uses this:

```
if ($_item->getProduct()->getTypeId() === Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::TYPE_CODE)
```

to determine whether a product is configurable. I am now wanting to alter that to detect whether the product is a bundle - but it turns out, there is no `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Bundle`. Nor is there a `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Bundle`. In fact, I can't see to find *any* dedicated bundle classes, anywhere - it's like they don't exist!

What is the reason for this? How are developers supposed to deal with bundled products, without methods like getChildrenIds or TYPE_CODE? Are just supposed to be hardcoding things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundled products were introduced after the release of Magento 1, and for reasons unknown, their implementation was separated out into a new module.  Magento's modular system and shared `config.xml` space allows for this sort of separation.

A quick glance at `Mage_Bundle` reveals a type class

```
app/code/core/Model/Product/Type.php
```

and a renderer

```
app/code/core/Block/Checkout/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
```

Answer (score 1):

The bundle products were added later in Magento (after 1.0).
It's a totally separate module. Check `Mage_Bundle`.